# Voronoi diagram clipping 3D

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, triangulation, voronoi

I know how to build an ordinary Voronoi diagram, but I need to build it in a non-convex area with sharp edges. Is there any way to avoid non-convex cells by using clipping?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe what you seek is *conforming* or *constrained*
Voronoi diagrams (and
Delaunay triangulations).

[image: Fig4]

In the figure, **PSLG** = Planar Straight-Line Graph.

> Li, Qi, Haisheng Li, Qiang Cai, and Yuewu Liu. "Generation of 2D Conforming Voronoi Diagram in Complex Domain." In *Applied Informatics and Communication: International Conference*, ICAIC 2011, Xi’an, China, August 20-21, 2011, Proceedings, Part IV, pp. 32-39. Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 2011.

Comment: Hello. If I have the constrained Delaunay triangulation, would you know if the construction of the Voronoï diagram is similar to the unconstrained case?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent: I believe so, yes. I'm guessing that this paper would explain the construction: Chin, Francis, and Cao An Wang. "Finding the constrained Delaunay triangulation and constrained Voronoi diagram of a simple polygon in linear time." *SIAM Journal on Computing* 28, no. 2 (1998): 471-486.

Comment: Joseph O'Rourke> Thanks. [Here is what I get](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/4466543/222910708-516d989f-58cb-4982-8dfc-6ffa3987af41.png). Does that look correct? It remains to clip the Voronoï cells to the two hexagons. But then the truncated cells will not be Voronoï cells. And in your picture, there are some interior constraint edges. With the way I use, these edges belong to the constrained Delaunay triangulation. But I'm wondering whether they should rather be some Voronoï edges.

Comment: I mean I'm not sure that a constrained Voronoï diagram is defined as the dual of a constrained Delaunay triangulation. The constraining edges must be some Voronoï edges, not some Delaunay edges. You see what I mean? I have to find a definition...

Comment: Check that paper I cited, but I myself have not read it, so I'm unsure if it contains what you seek.

Comment: [a pretty one](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/4466543/223277363-892f6eb9-5808-4f0c-bc90-cac102540cd2.png)